# how to use private key to encrypt data in Web Cryptography API

Tags: javascript, rsa, webcrypto-api

I have followed the [tutorial](http://qnimate.com/asymmetric-encryption-using-web-cryptography-api/) to use public key to encrypt data and use private key to decrypt data on browser.
But when I try to use private key to encrypt data, it fails with `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: key.usages does not permit this operation`.
How to use private key to encrypt data in Web Cryptography API?
And I am also looking for a javascript library which allows me to generate RSA key pairs, encrypt and decrypt data on browser. I have found some RSA javascript library, but them all need use open-ssl commands to generate RSA key pairs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1) it is too broad, 2) includes no code, and 3) asks for a library recommendation.

Comment: @user5440753 I am already working on the library that will let you generate RSA key pairs easily and smoothly right in the JavaScript using strong pseudo random number generator built on top of WebCrypto API.

Answer (score 2):

You can't encrypt with a private key in the Web Crypto APIs.

With RSA, it's technically possible to encrypt data with the private key, which can then be decrypted with the public key. But since the public key is presumed to be public, there's no secrecy to be gained by encrypting data with the private key.

What encrypting data with a private key does is allow the public to verify that the data was encrypted by someone in possession of the private key. This is the basis for cryptographic signatures. But since encrypting data with RSA is computationally expensive, rather than encrypting an entire block of data, we typically take a cryptographic hash and just encrypt the hash.

The Web Crypto APIs will generate RSA keys for you, and the link you gave even shows how to do it.